# How do I set default font for all Qt5 applications?

Tags: fonts, qt

In Qt4, there used to be a tool called qtconfig that allowed you to set the fonts and other stuff. It also picked up the settings from KDE4's control panel.

I'm working with Qt5 now (binary distribution downloaded from qt-project.org), but the default font in all Qt5 applications is too small for me. Is there any way I can increase it to match the rest of the desktop? My default Qt5 style is Fusion.

I tried playing with `~/.config/QtProject.conf` (copying the Qt4 settings there), but it didn't help.

I'm using openSUSE 12.2 x86-64.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried **Qt5Ct**?

from this [article](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/11/configure-qt5-application-style-icons.html)

> Unlike Qt4, Qt5 doesn't come with a configuration tool to allow setting the icon theme, fonts or the style and instead, it tries to use the settings from the running desktop environment. 
>   **To force the Qt5 style or icon theme, you can use an application called Qt5ct (Qt5 Configuration Tool). Besides the style and icons, Qt5ct can also be used to change various other Qt5 settings, such as fonts, add custom style sheets and tweak other interface settings such as the double click interval, enable icons in menus and dialog buttons and more.**

Here is the package [download](https://software.opensuse.org/package/qt5ct?search_term=qt5ct)